# Python 3 - What is a fast and memory efficient way to implement multidimensional indexing?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, indexing, python-3.4

I'm coding up a generalized implementation of `__index__` for some of my more branchy classes and it occurred to me to ask the crowd for its wisdom on this.

In short, I'm looking to convert a tuple of ints (n-dimensional indices) to an int (returned from `__index__`, kept as instance state) and back (setting/changing it (or maybe immutish?). The same with strings ('A4', 'C17', 'CDE42', 'CDE42YUP420', 'CDE42YUP420DEEP42', etc)

Anyway, here's what I'm thinking so far. I know it's just a skeleton at the moment, but I think it helps get the point of the question across. I'll update my question as I work on Idx on my end. I'll get some timeit results up once it's implemented enough to start trying out versions of it.

I'd appreciate any thoughts. Thanks!

```
class Idx:
    __slots__ = 'idx',
    def __init__(self, idx):
        ## Sorry about the if/elif block. It's for brevity
        if isinstance(idx, int):
            self.idx = idx
        elif isinstance(idx, tuple):
            ## idx == (0, 0) | (1920, 1080) | (42, 0, 420) ...
            ... ## Insert magic here
        elif isinstance(idx, str):
            ## idx == 'A0' | 'Z99' | 'C8' ...
            ... ## Insert magic here
        else:
            raise TypeError("What is this crap!?: ", repr(idx))

    def __index__(self):
        return self.idx

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from ...  ## insert magic here

    def __int__(self):
        ## not sure if I should implement int(self)..?
        ## I don't want Python to throw exceptions when I treat
        ## instances as normal ints (ie: not __index__), though
        return self.idx

    def __str__(self):
        return ...  ## insert magic here

    def __repr__(self):
        ## I <3 Recursion
        return "".join(("Idx(", repr(self.idx), ")"))
```

Comment: Like [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)?

Comment: Kinda. I'm looking to write a class whose objects can be used as an index in a slice. I was using `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and `__delitem__`, but that wasn't working with a slice. (ie: `[Idx((1,2,3)) : Idx((3, 3, 3))] `).

Comment: Oh ya. That really is what I'm looking for lol